# textfield label is not coming inside formpanel inside panel

Tags: extjs

I have designed one extjs page but my problem is

i have to give a textfield inside inner panel which is form panel but textfield label is not coming can you please solve...this is my code...but problem is i have to give employeeid inside one inner panel based on some condition i have to hide the inner panel but when i am creating panel i am not getting textfield label....can anyone please solve

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

 var tab2 = new Ext.FormPanel(
    {
        labelAlign: 'left',
        title: 'Main Panel',
        buttonAlign: 'left',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
        width:700,
        height:500, 
        method: 'POST',
        url : '../../WebPages/ServerTask.aspx',
        id: 'formTest',
        //anchor:'60%',
        collapsible: true,      
            items: [{layout:'column', border:false,
            items:[{columnWidth:.6,layout: 'form', border:false,labelWidth:120,
            items: [{
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel:'employeeid',
                       id:'employeeNo',
                       width:110
                    }]
              }]
              }]
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the problem. You are configuring the `items` config **three times**. There are more errors in your code but that is the one that breaks it.
Try this example and add/remove config you don't need.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Main Panel',
    buttonAlign: 'left',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
    width: 700,
    height: 500, 
    url : '../../WebPages/ServerTask.aspx',
    id: 'formTest',

    items: [{
        xtype:'textfield',
        fieldLabel:'employeeid',
        id:'employeeNo',
        width:110
    }],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Other errors:

1. Create your objects with the Ext.create function.
2. The layout config specifies the position of the child object so add the `layout` config to the parent.
3. Don't add child config to parent. see `labelAlign`
4. Begin an array with `[{` and close it with `}]`
5. Don't work with id's (only if you have to)